# Swagger code generation validation

Tags: swagger-2.0

I am trying to use swagger code gen to generate code enabling Bean Validation but couldn't. How to generate the code and enable Bean Validation using swagger 2.0.

Comment: Which target are you generating?

Comment: java -jar target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate
 -i http://localhost:8080/v2/swagger.json
 -l java
 -o samples/

Comment: I am using the above command to generate the code